Closed Set of Vertices
The question goes as follows:
Given a directed graph $G = (V, A)$ with weights $w_v$ on the vertices
for $v ∈ V$. Describe the problem of finding a closed subset of vertices
with maximum weight as an ILP problem.
A set of vertices $V′ ⊆ V$ is closed if all successors of every vertex $v ∈ V′$
are also included in the subset $V′$.
What does a closed set of vertices mean? By definition all successors of a vertex $v ∈ V′$ should be included. Say the vertices are named and weighted as $1, 2, .... , n$. Does that mean if I include 1, then all the other vertices should also be included since all the vertices must be successor to some vertex $v ∈ V′$? Also does it mean the maximum would be if all the vertices are included since we are striving for the maximum weight? But then they would not be asking this question......

Successor doesn’t mean “vertex with a larger index.” It can be defined recursively thus: “For any vertices $v,w \in V$, $w$ is a successor of $v$ if either (1) $(v,w) \in A$ or (2) $(z,w) \in A$ for some successor $z$ of $v$.”

In the definition of "successor"  the successors of a vertex $v$ are all the vertices you can reach from $v$ along a directed edge of the graph.
The names and weights of the vertices and the order in which they are listed are irrelevant.

I have understood now that successors are just immediate neighbors of v via arcs leaving v and a closed set is formed when there are no arcs leaving the set.
Writing the ILP formulation is straightforward. Using decision variable $x_v$ which is 1 when vertex v is included in the closed set and 0 otherwise, the ILP can be written as:
max $\sum_{v} x_{v}w_{v}$
s.t $x_{v1} \leq x_{v2} $ for all $(v_1, v_2) ∈A$
$x_v ∈ \{0,1\}$ for all $v ∈ V$
